# Why does github take public key through textarea instead of file upload?

Tags: github, ssh-keys

I'm curious why you have to `$ xclip -sel clip < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` and paste into `textarea` instead of just uploading your `id_rsa.pub`?

What benefits does this approach have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key file is relatively small and is a text file. There's no need to use the clunky browser "select a file" upload mechanism for something so small.

Answer (score 0):

An initial guess is that the file upload would retain the line endings while the textarea does not. This is purely a guess though.